# drop-down resetting does not visible in UI although the state value is reset ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a Select dropdown where I select options from the list and I have a "clear" button which is supposed to reset the drop selection once the button is clicked.

When the clear button is clicked, although I update the state object corresponding value with an empty string, it does not clear the dropdown. I am new to reactjs and any idea how to achieve this

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-dew-keidv?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: undefined,
      loading: false,
      count: []
    };
  }

  onFirstSelect = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        loading: true,
        value: value
      },
      //call the api and
      () => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          count: [value, 1]
        });
      }
    );
  };

  onClickRoute = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      !this.state.loading && (
        <div className="App">
          <select onChange={this.onFirstSelect} defaultValue={this.state.value}>
            <option>slect value</option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
          </select>
          &nbsp;
          <button onClick={() => this.onClickRoute()}>Clear Selection</button>
          <div>state value - {this.state.value}</div>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: If you're new to React, you should learn to make functional components instead of class components, this is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `value` in the `select` element. Currently, you are using `defaultValue`.

here is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-snow-psflb

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should assign select component value with your state value

```
<select
     value={this.state.value}
     onChange={this.onFirstSelect}
>
```

Here is a [Working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-albattani-5nxyn?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I don't think there is a need of defaultValue now as `value` will override the `defaultValue`